# What would electromagnetic field of concentric ball magnets look like?

Tags: electromagnetism

What is the scientific consensus for what electromagnetic fields of concentric ball magnets look like? This here is a few assumptions, poles on inside diameter of hollow shell reverse polarity to the poles on the outside diameter, attraction between poles on interior magnet and inside diameter of hollow shell along Y axis, and repulsion at the equator since magnetic field lines of the interior magnet flow in the opposite direction to those of the hollow shell in that region. With those assumptions as context to what the question is asking for, what is the correct model?

[image]

Comment: Simply define what is the magnetization of the region you consider. Magnetization, $\mathbf{M}$ is literally the density of magnetic dipoles per volume, so if you have a uniform North-South bar magnet, it would have constant magnetization inside it, and zero outside. Once you have written down the definition, all you will need to do is solve $\boldsymbol{\nabla}.\left(\mathbf{H}+\mathbf{M}\right)=0$ and $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\left(\mathbf{H-M}\right)=\mathbf{0}$. Where $\mathbf{H}$ is the magnetic field. See magnetostatic potential https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential

Comment: As attention is limited, for example many people use this stackexchange  but most are not expected to be able to build it from machine level and up, could you point me in the right direction using a bit higher level language? One thing I wonder, if the field inside the outer magnet is per closed loop rule, and the field around the inside magnet as well, would they repel at the sides when attracting at the poles?

Comment: If you are asking me whether I can give you a reference to where your particular question has been solved, then I do not know such reference. I don't think anyone would bother to write this up. My point is that if you can draw the picture with red and blue, as you did, then you can specify magnetization. If you can specify magnetization, then the whole problem reduces to solving a scalar Laplace equation - a standard problem in mathematical physics.

Comment: Not really asking you that, I am wondering if you know if when the magnets attract at poles, would they simultaneously repel at sides? It looks like that from magnetic field lines in drawings. Think of this as if you were asking someone, in a subject you are new in, perhaps strong cryptography (have no idea what your range expertise is), then you would be asking about things that to them were simple but to you complex.

Comment: Your title question was about magnetic field of ball magnets. Now, you seem to be asking a slightly different question. This second question seems to be simpler, which is good, but I can't quite understand what do you mean. Do you need to have nested magnets in a ball? Will two bar-magnets do instead?

Comment: It is about ball magnets. When ball magnets are placed inside one another, and attract at the poles, the magnetic field lines of both magnets look like they would repel at the sides. I'm trying to figure out if they would, this question was a way to get some insight into that.

Comment: Magnetic field lines do not act on each other. Electromagnetism in vacuum is linear. In matter it may not be linear (but this is more about solid state physics). Furthermore, magnetic field lines are not even 'real'. We use them for depiction, but there is no 'equation of magnetic field lines'. Only Maxwell's equations for the magnetic field. I think, when you talk about repelling field lines, you are simply after the shape of magnetic field. To get it you need to solve Maxwell's equations, or use a numerical package that solves them for you. Given the complexity of geometry, it is probably #2

Comment: Check out http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage and other solvers

Comment: I'm aware they are a representation :) Usually, in schematics, when field lines move in same direction there is attraction, when they move in opposite direction there is repulsion. In the arrangement I show in the drawing, if the magnets attract at the poles, it seems like it would be known, by experts in the subject, if they would repel at the sides.

Comment: I'm interested more in higher level language, for same reason most people using stackexchange are not aware of how to build it from logical gates, because attention is limited. So I turn to experts to have some processing done outside myself (reason Q&As are used in general)

Comment: Without solving equations, at least numerically, the only higher level language you can get is that magnetic field lines will be closed and curved. The difference between stackexchange (programming) and your question, is that computers are highly standartised entities with tons of documentations, and people spending their lives going through every detail. Yes, in this case they do not need to solve equations. They have seen it all before. But this, what is above, is a rather complex, but uninteresting problem. Why should anyone care to know the answer?

Comment: One thing that might answer the question, someone pointed me to this. It shows, I think, a magnet inside a hollow magnet, repelling at the poles and attracting at the sides, with attraction then stronger at the sides then at poles. I guess, since otherwise it ought to orient itself opposite. Would be good to have it validated by an expert. The drawing next to it is mine.
https://i.imgur.com/23WaDfI.png